# Four Square API use of section in query in R

Tags: r, api, foursquare

Defining `x`, `y`, and `z` as "10013","XXXX","20170104" and using

```
w <- paste("https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?near=",x,"&section='food'&oauth_token=",y,"&v=",z,sep="")
u <- getURL(w)
test <- RJSONIO::fromJSON(u)
```

does not return a good result, but if I replace `section='food'` with `query='food'` it will search for food in the name of the location
(I replaced the authorization token with `XXXX` here).

Comment: Is this a question? It's unclear what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

The [venues/search](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/search) endpoint you're using doesn't have a `section` parameter. The `section` parameter is valid with the [venues/explore](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/explore) endpoint if that's what you mean to be trying -> `https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/explore`

Note that `/search` and `/explore` are designed to accomplish very different things and you should read the docs before you just switch over.

**/explore** should be used to return recommended venues near a location. (example: coffee shop)

**/search** should be used to return a specific venue or venues near a location. (example: Starbucks)

Comment: Thanks,  Is there a way to get more than 50 locations with a query (I am interested in doing this with zip codes)?

Comment: Nope. The limit parameter accepts a number up to 50. If you need a lot of data you can try: https://enterprise.foursquare.com/contact-us

Comment: Why doesn't  "https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?categoryID=4bf58dd8d48988d1fa931735&near=10013&oauth_token=FUJIHC5WTTC4BJPV2FLE55M2BBGAHR2QKX5JKY05WVL1KMQ0&limit=50&v=20170110"

Comment: why doesn't w <-  "https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?categoryID=4bf58dd8d48988d1fa931735&near=10013&oauth_token=XXXX&limit=50&v=20170110"
u<-getURL(w)
test<-RJSONIO::fromJSON(u)   limit things to hotels?

Comment: @T.K. the categoryId parameter is case-sensitive it looks like you're using "categoryID" instead of "categoryId". Also, your comment about retrieving more then 50 locations - you can do this with multiple calls via the offset parameter, see my post here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41571392/how-to-get-all-the-venues-data-using-foursquare-api/41574814#41574814

Comment: I got categoryId to work, but offset did not work.  I used  "https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?categoryId=4bf58dd8d48988d1fa931735&near=10013&offset=50&oauth_token=XXXX&limit=50&v=20170112"

Comment: Does this mean that we can't go beyond 50 with search but only with explore?  I don't see an offset option here for search.

Comment: Offset doesn't work with venues/search. Venues/search is designed to find a specific venue so paging through results doesn't make a ton of sense for that use-case.

Comment: so there's no way to go beyond the count of 50 for a zipcode, then?  Thanks, Eric.

Comment: If zip code is your only reference to the location then yes, you're limited to 50 results with venues/search

Comment: I am using near to select zip code.  This does not work as well as I might like.  Is there a way to select on zip code?  Also, can we add country?  I have switched to the explore API so that I can use offset.  A sample query is (client_id and client_secret changed) "https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/explore?categoryId=4bf58dd8d48988d1fa931735&zip=50006&client_id=XXXX&client_secret=XXXX&limit=50&offset=0&v=20170206"