# How to get all the venues data using foursquare api

Tags: node.js, foursquare

I have created app in foursquare and get the client_id and client_secret key . I need all the restaurants details of a city.but i got only 50 restaurant details. Please help me . thanks in advance

```
'https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/explore?near=San Francisco,San Francisco&section=food&novelty=50&client_id=client_id&client_secret=client_secret&v=20170109';
```

Answer (score 2):

Matt is correct that you can use the `offset` parameter but his linked documentation and sample url was a little off.

It looks like you're using the venues/explore endpoint, you can find documentation on this here: https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/explore

To page through results you would set up something like this:

```
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/explore?client_secret=****&client_id=****&v=20161101&limit=50&near=San Francisco, CA&section=food
```

In your response (json) you should inspect the `json['response']['totalResults']` value to see how many results there are in total.

```
for (var i = 0; i < totalResults/50; i++) {
    url = 'https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/explore?client_secret=****&client_id=****&v=20161101&limit=50&near=San Francisco, CA&section=food&offset='(i + 1)*50';
}
```

It also looks like some of the parameters that you're using are invalid.

1. The near parameter should be `San Francisco, CA` not `San Francisco, San Francisco`
2. There is no `novelty` parameter with that API, do you mean to use `limit`?

Comment: Nice refined answer @enc_life. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `offset` parameter in order to page through the venues:

Here is the API docs:
https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/listed

The stated limit is 200 so the example below will return a list of results 201-400:
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/?limt=200&offset=201

```
for (var i = 0; i < numberOfPages; i++) {
    url = 'https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/?limt=200&offset=' + i * 200;
}
```